# How to fix ‘update php server time in unity3d'

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I wrote some code in unity that receive data from php server, i want to know server time in my game every second, (I live in iran) , when i execute the code without vpn(virtual private network) internet connection i have a problem , the problem is that "yield return www1" output update every minute. here is my unity c# code:
(when i turn vpn on that's work correctly and output update every second)

the variable $difference in php code is the difference between start time and now time,
with vpn the output in unity correctly showed every second but without vpn showed every minute, 
how to fix this?

```
void Update () {
StartCoroutine(Start2());
}

public IEnumerator Start2(){
            WWW www1 = new             
 WWW("http://54.37.95.30:80/Dogikio/calc_time.php");
        yield return www1;

        timer.text = www1.text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www1.error))
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www1.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www1.error);
        }
    }
```

and this is calc_time.php file:

```
<?php
  //Variables for the connection
    $servername = "127.0.0.1";
    $username1 =  "root";
    $password1 = "";
    $dbName = "ddd";



         $now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //Make Connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username1, $password1, $dbName);
    //Check Connection
    if(!$conn){
$resultstr="{'key':'register','result':'0','error':'Connection Failed.' 
}";
}


     $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM start_time") or die 
 ("{result:0,error:".mysqli_error($conn)."}");
     $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     $prev_time=$rows['start_time'];



 //Convert them to timestamps.
 $date1Timestamp = strtotime($now);
 $date2Timestamp = strtotime($prev_time);

 //Calculate the difference.
 $difference = $date1Timestamp - $date2Timestamp;


 echo($difference);

  ?>
```

Comment: Are you making a http request to a PHP file which makes a DB-query and returns the time _every second_?

Comment: the var $prev_time is from DB that i saved to DB before.

Comment: the var $difference is a number in second, for example 250s that's show 250 second past from start time

Comment: I'd really suggest you to use a node server with an asset like BestHTTP for that kind of thing. Way easier and more performant

Comment: yes,  Magnus Eriksson

Comment: note that you are not calling this *every second* but within `Update` so you will have a Coroutine running for **every frame**! I'ld guess your server is simply overloaded. You should definitely have something implemented that stops starting new routines until the last one finished! e.g. like `private bool alreadyRunning; private void Update() { if(!alreadyRunning) StartCoroutine(Start2()); }` and in `Start2` set this flag to `true` on the top and `false` on the bottom.

Comment: derHugo, Thanks for your answer, i tested the code without update for example every 5 second but the output for $difference will showed every 1 minute!!!   and when i testing with vpn(virtual private network) internet connection the output for $difference will showed every 1 second!